# LayoutRounding property is not defined

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, expression-blend

I have taken a copy of the XamlVirtualJoystick project located here 
https://github.com/shakram02/XamlVirtualJoystick

I wanted to convert it from a UserControl to a custom control, with the XAML code in a resource dictionary. (I don't know if that is relevant to the my error.)

In my project, the identical XAML generates the error message:

*The property 'LayoutRounding' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008'.*

This refers to the property **d:LayoutRounding="Auto"**, where the prefix d is defined as 
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"

I can compile the original project, so the property must be defined somewhere, but I cannot figure out where.

Where is the property LayoutRounding defined?

Comment: That was it. Thank you. (If you write the comment as an an answer I will mark it as the correct answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you have `mc:Ignorable="d"` in your xaml defined? d is usually the designer name space and mc:Ignorable="d"  says that all properties with prefix d: are to be ignored by the compliler and are only used in blend designer view.